# Is curl_multi_exec() a blocking call?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, curl-multi

Was just curious if the `curl_multi_exec()` call in PHP is blocking or non-blocking call.

Comment: Depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 6):

*Shot answer* : `curl_multi_exec()` is **non-blocking**

---

*Longer answer* : `curl_multi_exec()` is **non-blocking**, but **blocking can be made with the combination of `curl_multi_select`**, which blocks until there is activity on any of the curl_multi connections.

**Edit:**
Currently I am working on a crawler, this is outline of a piece of code I used.

```
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    if($to_db_queue->count()>0){
       while($to_db_queue->count()>0)
          //dequeue from queue and insert into database
    }
    else  
      curl_multi_select($mh); //block till state change
} while ($active > 0);
```

This code will make a `curl_multi_exec` and then will continue its database work queued in `$to_db_queue`, else if nothing in queue `curl_multi_select` will be called to block the loop until a state change occur in curl_multi connections.

Hope this will help you understand the concept.