# Amp PHP - cooperative multitasking / async sleep

Tags: php, async-await

In single thread PHP I need to write an app that:

- a) function as a HTTP server
- b) able to make some HTTP requests

a) and b) have to work even when the server is waiting/serving a request or HTTP client is waiting for reply

I came up with an idea to use the PHP Amp server. It works great.

However for the HTTP client I need to use a PHP curl.

My code looks like this:

```
...
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
do {
    AmpLoopHelper::asyncSleep(0.001);
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $isRunning);
} while ($isRunning && ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $mrc == CURLM_OK));
...
```

and the custom `AmpLoopHelper` class:

```
<?php

namespace Mvorisek\Dsv;

use Amp\Loop;
use Amp\Loop\Driver;


class AmpLoopHelper {
    /** @var int|null */
    private static $dummyWatcherId;

    /**
     * Async sleep and keep processing of Loop tasks.<br>
     * Loop\Driver::tick() is always called at least once even if
     * the sleep delay is zero or negative.
     * 
     * @param float $sleepSecs
     */
    public static function asyncSleep(float $sleepSecs): void {
        $t = microtime(true);

        // add dummy function to repeat to prevent Loop\Driver::tick() to block
        $maxCheckDelayMillis = min(max(1, $sleepSecs * 1000 / 50), 50);
        $isNested = static::$dummyWatcherId !== null;
        if (!$isNested) {
            static::$dummyWatcherId = Loop::repeat($maxCheckDelayMillis, static function() {});
        }

        try {
            do {
                if (static::loopDriverIsRunning()) {
                    static::loopDriverTick();
                } else {
                    usleep(($sleepSecs - (microtime(true) - $t)) * 1e6);
                    break;
                }
                usleep(40);
            } while(microtime(true) - $t < $sleepSecs);
        } finally {
            if (!$isNested) {
                Loop::cancel(static::$dummyWatcherId);
            }
        }
    }

    private static function loopDriverGet(): Driver {
        return \Closure::bind(static function() {
            return Loop::$driver;
        }, null, Loop::class)();
    }

    private static function loopDriverIsRunning(): bool {
        $driver = static::loopDriverGet();
        return \Closure::bind(static function() use($driver) {
            return $driver->running;
        }, null, Driver::class)();
    }

    private static function loopDriverTick(): void {
        $driver = static::loopDriverGet();
        \Closure::bind(static function() use($driver) {
            $driver->tick();
        }, null, Driver::class)();
    }
}
```

But the HTTP server is sometimes unaccessible. The helper class uses some private methods of Amp classes.

Is the idea of `asyncSleep` correct?

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP curl? Amphp has an asynchronous HTTP client. And your idea of `asyncSleep` is wrong. `usleep` puts the thread to sleep. Your thread blocks completely during that time. That's why your HTTP server is unaccessible. What you need is an asynchronous sleep, which is done with a timer and a promise. Once the timer fires, the promise gets resolved. In Amphp this async sleep can be simply done by yielding the promise and thus leads to an asynchronous sleep while keeping the event loop ticking. Read the Amphp documentation for more information about this.

Comment: But if you use Amphp's HTTP client you won't need an asynchronous sleep, because it's all handled by the event loop.

Comment: The `usleep(40);` there is a simple rate limit, ignore it. I can not use the Amphp's HTTP client as current code uses async curl and also I can not return yield/Generator from it. I need to return the processing power to the event loop.

Comment: Your best choice is to refactor your code. Your code is blocking - simply because of curl and `usleep`.

Comment: Where is the curl blocking? `usleep(40);` blocks max 40 us.

Comment: `curl_multi_exec` is a blocking I/O call. You should completely refactor your code. You should integrate your code into the event loop, not vice versa. You're having a bad time in the long run with that code.

Comment: It is not blocking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391368/is-curl-multi-exec-a-blocking-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `Driver->dispatch()` may be called with blocking flag and the blocking streams were not updated from my helper class.